# How does KeePassX sometimes start up automatically in Debian/KDE

Tags: debian, keepassx

I'm using the password database program KeePassX 0.4.3 on Debian 8.5 / KDE 4.14.2.
I configured KeePassX to start up minimized to tray, with the last opened database file opened and locked. I couldn't find an option to start KeePassX automatically on system start, but somehow it does automatically start up, **sometimes**.

What's going on? Why does it sometimes automatically start up? KeePassX is not listed in the Autostart utility of KDE. I also can't find it in /etc/init.d or /etc/systemd. Are there any more places in the Debian filesystem that contain startup programs?

I do want KeePassX to start up on system start and I know how to do that using the Autostart utility, but I don't want to sometimes run two instances of the program. It would be nice to hear how to fix this, but it would be even more nice if someone knows what goes wrong.

Comment: Look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/487920/how-to-control-programs-run-at-startup

Comment: I disabled KDE's session restore and added KeePassX to autostart. It looks like it works now.